# Почему при попытке разбить строку по повторяющимся буквам/символам, итерация проходит не по всей строке?

Tags: python, строки

Делю следующей функцией строку `('1111aa994bbbb1111AAAAAFF?<mmM!!!!!!!aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazzzzzzxxxxxxxxaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabf')`

по повторяющимся символам:

```
def find_longest_substr(s):
    for i, k in enumerate(s):
        if s[i] != s[i+1] and not s[i].isspace():
            s = s[:i+1] + ' ' + s[i+1:]
    return s

print(find_longest_substr('1111aa994bbbb1111AAAAAFF?<mmM!!!!!!!aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazzzzzzxxxxxxxxaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabf'))
```

Получаю ответ: `1111 aa 99 4 bbbb 1111 AAAAA FF ? < mm M !!!!!!! aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa zzzzzz xxxxxxxx aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabf`

Ожидал получить: `1111 aa 99 4 bbbb 1111 AAAAA FF ? < mm M !!!!!!! aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa zzzzzz xxxxxxxx aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa b f`

то есть, в конце символы тоже должны быть разделены пробелами. Вопрос следующий: почему в конце группа из букв "а", а также b и f не отделены друг от друга пробелами?

Comment: Простое правило: не модифицируйте коллекцию, по которой в этот момент итерируетесь. Чтобы не было проблем - просто создавайте новую строку вместо модификации старой.

Comment: Спасибо! Пытаюсь добавить в новую переменную и из этого у меня возникает вопрос: 

def find_longest_substr(s):
    a = ''
    for i, k in enumerate(s):
        if s[i] != s[i+1] and not s[i].isspace():
            a = s[:i+1] + ' ' + s[i+1:]
    return a

выдаёт ошибку 'IndexError: string index out of range'.
В чём проблема с моей новой переменной?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вам уже ответили в комментариях, не нужно менять итерируемый объект это может вызвать кучу проблем.

```
def find_longest_substr(string):
    result = ""
    for i, char in enumerate(string[:-1]):
        if char != string[i+1] and not char.isspace():
            result += char + ' '
        else:
            result += char
    return result + string[-1]# если последний симвл не повторяется, то тоже его добавим 

s = '1111aaи994bbbb1111AAAAAFF?<mmM!!!!!!!aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazzzzzzxxxxxxxxaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabf'
print(find_longest_substr(s))
```

Вывод:

```
1111 aa и 99 4 bbbb 1111 AAAAA FF ? < mm M !!!!!!! aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa zzzzzz xxxxxxxx aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa b f

[Program finished]
```

Comment: теперь я всё понял, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [`groupby()`](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-itertools-python/funktsija-groupby-modulja-itertools/) из модуля `itertools`.

```
from itertools import groupby


def find_longest_substr(s):
    return ' '.join(''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(s))


print(find_longest_substr('1111aa994bbbb1111AAAAAFF?<mmM!!!!!!!aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazzzzzzxxxxxxxxaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabf'))
```

```
1111 aa 99 4 bbbb 1111 AAAAA FF ? < mm M !!!!!!! aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa zzzzzz xxxxxxxx aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa b f
```

Comment: отдельное спасибо за вариант с библиотекой (на которую я натолкнулся, но как её использовать, так и не понял)!!!

Answer (score 2):

**Никогда** не изменяйте список который вы итерируете!

Я переписал ваш код так:

```py
def find_longest_substr(s):
    result = ''

    if not s: return  # Если нам передали пустую строку, завершаем.

    symbol = s[0]

    for i in s:
        if i != symbol:  # Если тек. символ не равен пред. символ, добавляем пробел.
            result += ' '
            symbol = i
        result += symbol

    return result


print(find_longest_substr('1111aa994bbbb1111AAAAAFF?<mmM!!!!!!!aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazzzzzzxxxxxxxxaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabf'))
```

Вывод:

```
11111 aa 99 4 bbbb 1111 AAAAA FF ? < mm M !!!!!!! aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa zzzzzz xxxxxxxx aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa b f
```

Comment: Последний символ `f` потеряли.

Comment: спасибо, я запомнил!)

Comment: @CrazyElf переписал.